# Control Rig axis are broked

Tags: unreal-engine4

I want to make my character aim using control rig. But for some reason my character are rotating in the wrong axis and i don't know why.

I tried change the axis (primary and secondary) to some random values but i can't get it to work and i watched also a lot of tutorials and i don't think that i'm doing something wrong.

**My control rig**
[image]

**My Character BP (SETTING THE AIM AT VARIABLE):**
[image]

**My anim BP:**
[image]

**THE RESULT:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have correct parameters such as meters or centimeter in order to sync your base model with your correct paramters.

You can also try an addon of import rig from blender to UE4.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the scale of your character as per the requirements of UE4.

You can refer the [UE4 Documentation](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/game+development/9781784394905/1/ch01lvl1sec11/common-measurements-in-unreal-engine-4#:%7E:text=The%20dimensions%20of%20a%20player,to%20400(uu)H.) for the scale measurement